# Python Random Forest Regressor Erroring on nan values, despite removal

Tags: python, random-forest

I have a data set that is clean, with zero nan values, but I continue to get the same error on the regressor.  my frame is called new_player_data

I've tried finding any by

```
list(new_player_data.where(new_player_data.isna()).count() > 0)
```

which returns

[False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False]

some two hundred times. I thought that there might be some float that is too large. I attempted this:

```
for i in new_player_data.columns[:]:
    if new_player_data[i].dtype == float:
        new_player_data[i] = round(new_player_data[i],2)
```

no matter what I get:

```
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-327-3a664017ddaa> in <module>
----> 1 regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    248 
    249         # Validate or convert input data
--> 250         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    251         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    252         if sample_weight is not None:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    571         if force_all_finite:
    572             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 573                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    574 
    575     shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
     54                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     55             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
---> 56             raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
     57 
     58 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Any ideas on what else I might check here? at a total loss

Comment: I'm sure some folks will complain that there's not a data set here, but it's rather large, and I'm not looking for a magic answer per se just some ideas for what I can try to find what might be causing this error.

Comment: Your `nan` check is broken. Try `new_player_data.notna().all(axis=None)`.

Comment: that might be right, but still no dice. new_player_data.notna().all(axis=None)
response was:
True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @gmds for leading to the answer, turns out it was inf values, found via

```
infs = np.where(np.isinf(new_player_data))
infs

out: (array([ 261, 1162, 1190, 1339, 1365, 1451, 1656, 1736, 1878, 1954, 2189,
    2299, 2741, 3137, 3162, 3799, 3821, 3881, 4305]),
 array([ 3, 43, 43,  3, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 23, 43,  3, 43, 43, 43,  3,
    23, 43]))
```

I then replaced them thusly

```
pd.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True
infs = np.where(np.isinf(new_player_data))
infs
out: (array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

thanks gmds for the directional help!